# How do I print out newly added variables within a SAS dataset in SAS studio

Tags: sas

So I imported a SAS dataset and specified the desired variables while correctly formating them.

```
FILENAME currency '/folders/myfolders/SAS assignment/Assignment4/currency.txt';

data assn4.currency;
    infile currency;
    input 
    @1  currencynotes $3.
    @6  purchasedate mmddyy10.
    @19 purchasevalue 7.0000
    @30 selldate mmddyy10.
    @44 sellvalue 7.0000
    @55 numberofnotespurchased;
```

I then added in a number of SAS variables based on the other variables

```
data assn4.currency;
 set assn4.currency;
 Timeheld = selldate-purchasedate;
run;

data assn4.currency;
 set assn4.currency;
 value_at_dollar_per_purchase = numberofnotespurchased/purchasevalue;
run;

data assn4.currency;
 set assn4.currency;
 value_at_dollar_per_sale = numberofnotespurchased/sellvalue;
run;

data assn4.currency;
 set assn4.currency;
 profit= value_at_dollar_per_sale-value_at_dollar_per_purchase;
run;

data assn4.currency;
 set assn4.currency;
 PPD = profit/Timeheld;
run;
```

I then wanted to format and print out the dataset along with these new variables, however I do not know the spacing of these new variables and the dataset created in my ASSN4 library has column numbers instead of the spacing information i used from the imported txt file.

```
data assn4.currency;
 infile currency;
 input 
 @1  currencynotes $3.
 @6  purchasedate mmddyy10.
 @19 purchasevalue 7.0000
 @30 selldate mmddyy10.
 @44 sellvalue 7.0000
 @55 numberofnotespurchased
 @65 Timeheld mmddyy10.
 value_at_dollar_per_purchase 12.00000000
 value_at_dollar_per_sale 12.00000000
 profit 12.0000000000
 PPD 12.0000000000
 ;
```

when I attempt to print out my dataset using 
    Proc Print data = assn4.currency;
    run;

all these new variables had . denoting missing info, while the new dataset created that is in the library shows these values.

Comment: Did you want that last step to WRITE a new text file from your dataset?  If so you need to use `FILE` and `PUT` statements instead of `INFILE` and `INPUT` statements. You would also need a `SET` statement read in the dataset you want to write out. Also there is no need to also write a SAS dataset at the same time so you could use `_NULL_` as the dataset name in the `DATA` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to keep my answer simple and short despite the fact that it seems you lack some basic SAS knowledge.

In a `data` step, you use `infile` to read from an external file. To read from a SAS data set, you use a `set` statement.

In the first step, you created a dataset called `currency` in a library called `assn4` by reading from your text file. In the next few steps, you correctly add variables to that dataset, although all this could be done in one step.

However in the last step, you overwrite your dataset by reading again from your text file (with the `infile` statement). You then of course lose all the variables you had created.

This does what (I think) you are trying to achieve:

```
FILENAME currency '/folders/myfolders/SAS assignment/Assignment4/currency.txt';

data assn4.currency;
infile currency;
input 
  @1  currencynotes $3.
  @6  purchasedate mmddyy10.
  @19 purchasevalue 7.
  @30 selldate mmddyy10.
  @44 sellvalue 7.
  @55 numberofnotespurchased
;
Timeheld = selldate-purchasedate;
value_at_dollar_per_purchase = numberofnotespurchased/purchasevalue;
value_at_dollar_per_sale = numberofnotespurchased/sellvalue;
profit= value_at_dollar_per_sale-value_at_dollar_per_purchase;
PPD = profit/Timeheld;
format
 Timeheld mmddyy10.
 value_at_dollar_per_purchase
 value_at_dollar_per_sale
 profit
 PPD 12.
;
run;
```

Note that I changed your formats to what they are actually equivalent to. Adding a bunch of zeros after the dot in a format does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Yes I am just starting to learn SAS. Thanks so much, your code makes a lot of sense, the way my instructor explains certain SAS concepts can be a bit confusing at times.